# Redux: What is the correct place to save cookie after login request?

Tags: cookies, redux

I have the following situation: The user enters his credentials and clicks a *Login* button. An API call is done in the action creator via `redux-thunk`. When the API call was successful, another action is dispatched containing the response from the server. After the (successful) login I want to store the users session id in a cookie (via `react-cookie`).

**Action creator**

```
export function initiateLoginRequest(username, password) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(loginRequestStarting())

    return fetch('http://path.to/api/v1/login',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: username,
          password: password
        })
      })
      .then(checkStatus)
      .then(parseJSON)
      .then(function(data) {
        dispatch(loginRequestSuccess(data))
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        dispatch(loginRequestError(error))
      })
  }
}

export function loginRequestSuccess(user) {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS,
    user
  }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
export default function user(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
      cookie.save('sessionId', action.user.sid, { path: '/' })
      return merge({}, state, {
        sessionId: action.user.sid,
        id: action.user.id,
        firstName: action.user.first_name,
        lastName: action.user.last_name,
        isAuthenticated: true
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Right now the reducer responsible for *LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS* saves the cookie. I know the reducer has to be **a pure function**.

Is saving a cookie in the reducer violating this principle? Would it be better to save the cookie inside the action creator?

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).

You can persist/save your reducers (or parts of them) in `LocalStorage`.

## Concept

- Initiate login.
- Receive cookie from server.
- Dispatch login success.
- Reducer stores cookie in memory.
- Persist middleware stores reducer state in LocalStorage.

## Example

### Install

```
npm install --save-dev redux-persist
```

### Example Usage

Create a component that wraps the persistence/rehydration logic.

`AppProvider.js`

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';

class AppProvider extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        children: PropTypes.node
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { rehydrated: false };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const opts = {
            whitelist: ['user'] // <-- Your auth/user reducer storing the cookie
        };

        persistStore(this.props.store, opts, () => {
            this.setState({ rehydrated: true });
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.rehydrated) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <Provider store={this.props.store}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

AppProvider.propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.node
}

export default AppProvider;
```

Then, in your `index.js` or file in which you set up the `store`, wrap the rendered components in your new `AppProvider`.

`index.js`

```
...
import AppProvider from 'containers/AppProvider.jsx';
...

render((
    <AppProvider store={store}>
        ...
    </AppProvider>
), document.getElementById('App'));
```

This will serialize your `user` reducer state to `LocalStorage` on each update of the store/state. You can open your dev tools (Chrome) and look at `Resources` => `Local Storage`.

Comment: This approach looks good! I somehow thought using a cookie for the users access token would be supported by more browsers. I will take a look at the  current support for `localstorage`.

Comment: for those who want another opinion about it, follow the [link](https://medium.com/@clrksanford/persist-ence-is-key-using-redux-persist-to-store-your-state-in-localstorage-ac6a000aee63)

Comment: It's not secure to store tokens and other secure information in localStorage :(

Comment: @Roman, that entirely depends on if your app is susceptible to XSS.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is the "right" way, but that's how my team is persisting the logged user in the Redux app we built:

We have a very default architecture, an API ready to receive requests in one side, and a React/Redux/Single Page app that consumes this API endpoints in the other side.

When the user credentials are valid, the API's endpoint responsible for the login respond to the app with the user object, including an access token. The access token is latter used in every request made by the app to validate the user against the API.

When the app receives this user information from the API two things happen: 1) an action is dispatched to the users reducer, something like `ADD_USER`, to include this user in the users store and 2) the user's access token is persisted in the `localStorage`.

After this, any component can connect to the users reducer and use the persisted access token to know who is the logged user, and of course if you have no access token in your `localStorage` it means the user is not logged in.

In the top of our components hierarchy, we have one component responsible to connect to the users reducer, get the current user based on the access token persisted in the `localStorage`, and pass this current user in the [React's context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). So we avoid every component that depends on the current user to have to connect to the users reducer and read from the `localStorage`, we assume that this components will always receive the current user from the app's context.

There are some challenges like token expiration that adds more complexity to the solution, but basically this is how we are doing it and it's working pretty well.

Comment: Thank you, sounds pretty much like what we are building. Can you tell me, why you chose `localstorage` over Cookie (for saving the access token)?

Comment: Since we have no web server to keep users sessions, the logical solution was to use the localStorage

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably have the server-side set the cookie, personally, and make it transparent to JavaScript. But if you really want to do it client-side, I'd do it in an action helper. Something like this:

```
// Using redux-thunk
function login(user, password) {
  return dispatch => api.auth.login(user, password)
    .then(result => setCookie())
    .then(() => dispatch({type: 'USER_LOGGED_IN'}))
}
```

Or something like that.

Action helpers don't need to be pure, but reducers should be. So, if I'm doing side-effects, I put them into action helpers.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that today. It did feel kind of wrong saving (and deleting) cookies in my user reducer.